# jQuery $each very slow

Tags: jquery

I've got a "live search" box that searches through a `HTML table` and shows/hides depending on the search query.

This works perfectly fine for smaller tables, however as the table data grows searching becomes extreamly slow.

My code:

```
   $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var raderna = $("#history tbody tr");
        var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
           if(value.length == 0) {

              raderna.each(function(index) {
            if (index !== 0) {
                $row = $(this);
                    if($row.hasClass("hiddenRow")) {
                        $row.hide();
                    } else {
                        $row.show();
                    }
                }
          });

              return false;
       }
        raderna.each(function (index) {
            $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
                $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
                return not_found;
            });
        });
    });
```

Any ideas what I could do to speed it up?

Comment: Concatenate all the fields of a table row into string and push it into an array.Now you can just loop over this array to search for your string.

Comment: If you can use angularjs have a look at it.This process is really simple if you can use ng-repeat with ng-filter.

Comment: I second the idea of using a JavaScript object/array to manage the live searching. Working with the DOM is generally a lot slower than directly with variables. Perhaps you could store all the table data in a JSON file, and dynamically generate the table from it on page load? It'll probably be a bit slower to fully load the page, but then you could kill two birds with one stone - a faster lookup, and still have only a single file that needs updating as the contents of the table change. (And I feel JSON is a bit more readable/portable than HTML for this sort of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Put `var raderna = $("#history tbody tr");` above your keyup event. With every keyup event you are looking in DOM for `#history tbody tr` so it has a lot useless work to do. You can do this once on page load and keep it in that variable.
2. You can style class `hiddenRow` to have `display: none` and instead of calling `$row.hide()` and `$row.show()` you can `$row.addClass()` or `removeClass()`. It's quickier to add or remove class than to show or hide elements. Or you can even use toggleClass().
3. This each:

   ```
   $(this).find("td").each(function () {
       var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
       var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
       $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
       return not_found;
   });
   ```

   can be quickier if you write it like this:

   ```
   $(this).find('td').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this),
           id = $this.text().toLowerCase(),
           not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
       $this.closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
       return not_found;
   });
   ```

While I was writing it I saw that @Tyranicangel commented your question and I think that both his suggestions are good. I gave you only small tips for improving performance of your code.